# MapView Set Location

Tags: ios, mapkit

Can anyone help me with a problem I have with a mapView application that is only displaying the default location and not the specific location I have specified. My code is as follows. I'm learning Xcode so have probably made a schoolboy error :-

.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface RavenMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

-(void) goLocation;
@end
```

.M

```
#import "RavenMapViewController.h"


@implementation RavenMapViewController

@synthesize mapView;


-(void) goLocation 

{

    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.center.latitude = 39.278112;
    newRegion.center.longitude = -76.622772;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.008388;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.016243;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [self goLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload 

{


}

@end
```

Comment: Are you using a xib?  If so, is the IBOutlet connected to the map control in the xib?

Comment: I'm using storyboard - but it's resolved now thanks. I didn't have the IBOutlet connected up properly